# Catch block is not executed when try block method is failed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver

I wrote a try catch block to execute the test and if its fails then take screenshot in catch block. But catch block is not executed and the @After method is executed when the method in try block is failed. See the code below.

I am unable to understand where i am going wrong here.

```
@Test
public void testScenarios(){
    try {
        test();
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        log.info("Capturing the screenshot for the failed test.");
        takeScreenshot();
    }
}

public void test() {

    MyAccountPage myAccountPage = initElements(driver(), MyAccountPage.class);
    myAccountPage.clickOrderHistoryAndDetails();

    OrderHistoryPage orderHistoryPage = initElements(driver(), OrderHistoryPage.class);
    orderHistoryPage.selectLatestOrder();
    orderHistoryPage.verifyProduct(colour);

}
```

my test will be failining in orderHistoryPage.verifyProduct(colour); due to unable to locate element.

Comment: How do you know that the _test()_ method is failing? The _catch_ block will be called if _test()_ throws an _Exception_. Put a logger in _try_ block below _test()_ method and check whether it really is throwing an _Exception_. Moreover, check the methods in _test()_ method. It's possible that they're implicitly doing exception handling.

Comment: What kind of failure?  Is there an assertion that fails, or an exception?  When an assertion fails, an `Error` is thrown, not an `Exception`.

Comment: my test will be failing in orderHistoryPage.verifyProduct(colour); due to unable to locate element. I wantedly added incorrect element xpath. so it is failing but screenshot is not captured.

Comment: The exception received upon running the test is          org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id = 'order-list1']/tbody/tr/td[@data-value = 20180920071210]/preceding-sibling::td[@class = 'history_link bold footable-first-column']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=68.0.3440.84)

Comment: Did you set `log` to something?  Perhaps your first exception is immediately followed by a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: No only exception is thrown. I found my mistake and rectified it. First of fall the control was not going to try at all. so fixed that issue and not catch block is executed whenever the try block is failed and screenshot(s) are captured accordingly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The "test" method doesn't throw any exception.

```
//Exception is generic, you can throw your own Exception subclass
public void test() throws Exception{

    if(OK){
      //Good code
    }else{
      //Launch your exception. Es.
      throw new Exception();
    }

 }
```

Obviously, you can choose the execution logic you prefer, this is only an example.

In your case, the method "verifyProduct" instead of catch the error, should throw it to the caller.

I don't know how "verifyProduct" works, but it could be something like this:

```
if(!orderHistoryPage.verifyProduct(colour)){
   throw new Exception();
}
```

But this is only in case verifyProduct return boolean value if it doesn't find the element (Es. 1 for success, 0 for error)

For more info, check [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake and rectified it. First of fall the control was not going to try at all. so fixed that issue and now catch block is executed whenever the try block is failed and screenshot(s) are captured accordingly. Thanks for your help guys.